# Merging two data frames according to row values

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have two data frames, each with the same two columns: county codes and frequencies. They aren't identical, but some of the county code values show up in both data frames. Like this:

```
"county_code","freq"
"01011",2
"01051",1
"01073",9
"01077",1

"county_code","freq"
"01011",4
"01056",2
"01073",1
"01088",6
```

I want to merge them into a new data frame, such that if a county code appears in both data frames, their respective frequencies are added together. If the county code just appears in one or the other of the data frames, I want to add it (and its frequency) to the new data frame unchanged. The result should look like this:

```
"county_code","freq"
"01011",6
"01051",1
"01056",2
"01073",10
"01077",1
"01088",6
```

The result doesn't have to be ordered. I tried to use reshape for this, but I wasn't sure that was the right approach. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine the two data frames with `rbind`, then use `aggregate` to collapse multiple rows with the same `county_code`:

```
aggregate(freq~county_code, rbind(d1, d2) , FUN=sum)
##   county_code freq
## 1        1011    6
## 2        1051    1
## 3        1073   10
## 4        1077    1
## 5        1056    2
## 6        1088    6
```

(Using the definitions in MrFlick's answer.)

Comment: I'm sure this would be faster than any `merge` approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. I used `rbind()`,`merge()` and `dplyr`.

```
# sample data
country <- c("01011", "01051", "01073", "01077")
value <- c(2,1,9,1)
foo <- data.frame(country, value, stringsAsFactors=F)


country <- c("01011","01056","01073","01088")
value <- c(4,2,1,6)
foo2 <- data.frame(country, value, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(dplyr)

group_by(rbind_list(foo, foo2), country) %>%
summarize(count = sum(value))

ana

  country count
1   01011     6
2   01051     1
3   01056     2
4   01073    10
5   01077     1
6   01088     6
```

The other idea I had was the following.

```
ana2 <- merge(foo, foo2, all = TRUE, by = "country") 

  country value.x value.y
1   01011       2       4
2   01051       1      NA
3   01056      NA       2
4   01073       9       1
5   01077       1      NA
6   01088      NA       6

bob2 <- ana2 %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(count = sum(value.x,value.y, na.rm = TRUE))

  country value.x value.y count
1   01011       2       4     6
2   01051       1      NA     1
3   01056      NA       2     2
4   01073       9       1    10
5   01077       1      NA     1
6   01088      NA       6     6
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but what is "%>%" doing?

Comment: That is an operator which you use in dplyr. You may find [this link](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/05/21/dplyr-0-2/) useful.

Comment: As I don't have `dplyr` installed just now I am not sure, but it looks like you're doing a merge on both columns in the first example.  If so, this will still fail if there is a row that is identical in both data frames.  To see this, change the first definition of `value` to `value <- c(4,1,9,1)`.  `merge` will by default not repeat the row for `country == "01011"` and thus the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Thanks for your advice. Since you removed your comment yesterday, I went back to the original idea. I tested your idea and confirmed that I should go with rbind here. Thank you very much for your support. I will revise my suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

Using base functions, you can do a `merge()` then `transform()`. here are your sample input data.frames

```
d1 <- data.frame(
    county_code = c("1011", "1051", "1073", "1077"), 
    freq = c(2L, 1L, 9L, 1L)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
    county_code = c("1011", "1056", "1073", "1088"),
    freq = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 6L)
)
```

then you would just do

```
transform(merge(d1, d2, by="county_code", all=T), 
    freq = rowSums(cbind(freq.x, freq.y), na.rm=T), 
    freq.x = NULL, freq.y = NULL
 )
```

to get

```
  county_code freq
1        1011    6
2        1051    1
3        1056    2
4        1073   10
5        1077    1
6        1088    6
```